# How do I populate an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, double, text-files, populate

Okay so I have a textfile with only 2 lines of doubles that are comma separated. This will always be the case. Each line will have to go into its own separate array of type double where I will later have to use a linear search to find one array in the other.
example of the textfile:

```
2.5,6.7,3.4,7,6.7,6,4,5,83.6
6.4,7,8,5.3,9,76
```

So far I have managed to extract the first line, remove the delimiter and convert it from a string to type double BUT I am having difficulty putting it into an array. 
I have tried using while loops, for loops (sometimes nested) but they all do not work. I know there is meant to be a simple solution but I can't seem to grasp it or the concept of arrays.

The furthest I am able to code (without messing up) is to simply display it. but I need it in an array. My code follows. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    double array[10];
    int count = 0 ;
    string values;
    int I =0;
    ifstream inputfile.open("numbers.txt");
    if (!inputfile.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"error opening file"<<endl;
    }

    if (inputfile.good())
    {
        string line;
        string num;
        getline(inputfile,line);
        values= slime;
        string stream ss(values);
        while (getline (ss,num ,','))
        {
            cout<<stod(num)<<" ";
            //HOW DO I PUT THIS INTO THE ARRAY INSTEAD PLEASE??
        }
    }

    inputfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few things - one try not to use [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) 
  second - you check [inputfile.good()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/) only relevant **after** reading 
  third - you need an index to run over the array so I added the I that increment with the loop, But I didn't check if it counts more then thy array length so if it relevet add a check for that to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    double array[10];
    int count = 0 ;
    string values;
    int I =0;
    ifstream inputfile.open("numbers.txt");
    if (!inputfile.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"error opening file"<<endl;
    }

    string line;
    string num;
    getline(inputfile,line);
    values= slime;
    string stream ss(values);
    int i=0;
    while (getline (ss,num ,','),)
    {
        cout<<stod(num)<<" ";
        array[i] = stod(num);
        ++i;
    }
    inputfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Yaodav! This definitely helped and I can now proceed with the code. Really appreciate it.